# Recalling and Invoking Approval Process record locking is inconsistent

Tags: apex, approval-process, locking

I’m facing one weird consistency issue in locking / unlocking of records on Recalling Approval process and invoking the same Approval process again.

I have a requirement where on click of LWC Action button, some fields get updated and submitted for approval each time. Submission of record can happen even when there is already an approval process in progress for the same record, so I had to recall it and re-submit it.

During submission there would an email sent out for approval to Submitter’s Manager. There is an initial submission action which locks the record and updates the status to “Pending Approval”.

Approval Process screenshot
[image]

Here is my approval history screenshot,
I would like to know how to make this locking & unlocking consistently.
5,6 7,8 shows correct locking and unlocking, but 1,2 3,4 shows the final latest record as unlocked.

[image]

Here is my relevant code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void submitForApproval(String requestedParams){
        try{
            ApprovalRequest__c existingRec;
            Boolean approvalInProgress = false;
            Id piWorkItemId = null;
            Approval.ProcessResult result;
    
// existing record & loan record query goes here
            
            ApprovalRequest__c objApprovalRqst = (existingRec != null) ? existingRec : new ApprovalRequest__c();            
objApprovalRqst.Approver1__c = loanRecord.Credit_Manager__c;

// other mappings and updates goes here

upsert objApprovalRqst;

for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem eachWI : [SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :objApprovalRqst.Id AND ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending']){
                approvalInProgress = (eachWI != null) ? true : false;
                piWorkItemId = eachWI?.Id;
            }

            /****recalling approval Process******/

            if(approvalInProgress){
                Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest Preq = new Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest();
                Preq.setAction('Removed');
                Preq.setWorkItemId(piWorkItemId);
                result = Approval.process(Preq);
            }
            
            /****invoking approval Process******/
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest processSubmitReq = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            processSubmitReq.setComments('Need Approval for - XXXXXX');
            processSubmitReq.setObjectId(objApprovalRqst.Id);
            processSubmitReq.setSubmitterId(UserInfo.getUserId());
            processSubmitReq.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('XXXXXXXXXX ');
            processSubmitReq.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {objApprovalRqst.Approver1__c});
            processSubmitReq.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
            
            result = Approval.process(processSubmitReq);
```